# How to exclude an inventory group from 'all' by default in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, continuous-deployment, ansible-inventory

I'm setting up a small project in ansible, with a shared node with other projects. This node is the CI runner, and should rarely be the target of a playbook.

**I want to exclude a group from `all` by default**

The current solution that I have is just to have a group called bystanders, and exclude it from all playbooks that run `all`

hosts:

```
[groupA]
node1
[bystanders]
ci-node
```

playbook_example:

```
hosts: all:!bystanders
...
```

But this is prone to error, or forgetting to exclude that in some playbook, inadvertently running a playbook on that node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question somewhere else, and [Dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#developing-inventory) scripts were mentioned.

The dynamic inventory returns 'all' and 'ungrouped', so we can manipulate the results for these variables with dynamic inventory scripts.

```
{
    "_meta": {
            "hostvars": {}
    },
    "all": {
            "children": [
                    "ungrouped"
            ]
    },
    "ungrouped": {}
 }
```

However, in that conversation it was mentioned that 'all' is a bit of an anti-pattern, and avoiding it might be a good idea in the first place. 'all' means all, and in this case nothing that is project specific should use 'all'.

So I think this answers the question for me. I will avoid the use of all and in case I really need to do this, I will go with the dynamic inventory scripts